# Table scroll fixed height in Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way how to fix scroll that depends on screen , the scroll should display at the bottom of my screen. Whenever I zoom in and out the scroll should remain and visible at the bottom of screen. I tried adjusting the height to `height:auto` but the scroll didn't display at the bottom otherwise it display at the bottom that depends on my data. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image]

Reference : [fiddle](https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa)

```css
<style type="text/css">
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.intro {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 450px;
}
.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;

}
.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {

  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table-scroll thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/* safari and ios need the tfoot itself to be position:sticky also */
th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;

}
thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <table id="main-table" class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >Header 1</th>
        <th >Header 2</th>
        <th >Header 3 with longer content</th>
        <th >Header 4 text</th>
        <th >Header 5</th>
        <th >Header 6</th>
        <th >Header 7</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First top Column</th>
        <td>Cell content<br>
          test </td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
 
   
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column<br>
          last</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column<br>
          last</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set outsite tag `html, body{height: 100%;}` then set height table 100% `.table-scroll {  height: 100%;}`. It will set height table content auto fit with window

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.intro {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-scroll thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* safari and ios need the tfoot itself to be position:sticky also */

th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <table id="main-table" class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3 with longer content</th>
        <th>Header 4 text</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First top Column</th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column<br> last
        </th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column<br> last
        </th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it didn't limit the table scroll [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8tOv.png) the problem is when I set the height into 100% it will based the data that comes from the tbody of my table and it filter all of my data in table.

Comment: Then just set .table-scroll down to 35%. Then your table will be responsive. This is what you want to achieve right, make your web responsive. You could check this:[codepen](https://codepen.io/hoang1510-dt/pen/RwGdeoy)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use flex and flex-grow structure from bootstrap. It is useful to recommend about how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are options for the table tag. The options can be seen by

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('table-scroll');
```

Whenever resize screen size, I set the scroll position in the table at the bottom of the table.

Reference: [fiddle](https://codepen.io/jacobkim9881/pen/bGwZLYP)

Comment: It doesn't work for me I tried   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8tOv.png)

Comment: @MarieLoise Did you try to resize it? You should tell me how things not work so I can fix the problem.

Comment: @MarieLoise I edited the fiddle like the table at the bottom for the first time. Is it helpful?

Comment: thanks for your response this is what actually looks like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwxBO.jpg) as you can see there are different screen size the other one it works fine but when I switch to smallest one it didn't work because of the size and also I adjust the height of my table-scroll to  `550px;`

Comment: @MarieLoise Thanks for the detail but I don't get what the problem is. As I understand your question, the size of the height isn't the problem. Because what I added to the code is setting the scroll of the table at the bottom when the window is resized and is setting the scroll of the table at the bottom when window is loaded.